# How to clear inserted data into db from button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have this reference to a method (`Botones`) in my `codebehind` file:

```
public partial class EnvianosTuCurriculum : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Botones botones = new Botones();
        botones.SaveCVInfo2(nombre.Text, Apellidos.Text, EmpleoS.Text, DireccionPersonal.Text, RadioButtonList6.SelectedItem.Text, contraseña.Text, TelHabi.Text, TelCel.Text, userEmail.Text, Nacionalidad.Text, LugarNaci.Text, FechaNac.Text, Edad.Text, Cedula.Text, EsCivil.Text, ProUofi.Text, Estatura.Text, Peso.Text, TipoSang.Text, RadioButtonList7.SelectedItem.Text, Lateralidad.Text, LicCond.Text, RadioButtonList5.SelectedItem.Text, MaMoVeh.Text, RadioButtonList4.SelectedItem.Text, EmpCta.Text, ProMens.Text, SuelAs.Text, RadioButtonList3.SelectedItem.Text, NomRec.Text, RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Text,Insti.Text, horario.Text, vivequien.Text, RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text, otresp.Text, Ciudad.Text);
        Response.Redirect("Envia2.aspx");
    }

}
```

Now, if I add another button `Button2` I need to go back to previous page, and also clear all data sent to Database from these controls.

I guess i need an `if` statement there, but i just can add a `Response.Redirect("previous_page.aspx")`, don't know how to actually clear the data into db.

With `Response.Redirect` i can just go back and all fields look empty, but i will start filling them again, as a new user, i need to not only go back, but also undo all the data inserted into the db table.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You should issue a `DELETE` statement to the SQL-Server with the proper primary key associated with the record you want to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i would first add Validators and any other relevant controls to ensure that the data entered is what it should be and/or store the data temporarily before committing it to the database (which would avoid deleting it).

However if this is not applicable to delete data in SQL you would have something along the lines of

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Have a look at this link for further info/understanding http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Comment: Thank you! I just solved it by using an PK ID column session, so if i go back i can edit data, and it is restored into that session, but thank you very much anyway!